# Create one-way relationship without foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a problem with relationships I'm trying to form between some models.

I have a **Node** which has many **NodeTasks**. This is modelled so that NodeTask `belongs_to :node`, which works as expected.

I would also like to add a reference to an arbitrary **NodeTask** on **Node** - let's say `first_node_task`, as an optional attribute. This is where I'm having trouble.

I was able to hack it together so that `node.first_node_task` could be set and worked as expected with the following migration:

```
add_reference :nodes, :first_node_task, { type: :uuid, foreign_key: { to_table: :node_tasks } }
```

And model:

```
class Node
  belongs_to :first_node_task, class_name: 'NodeTask', foreign_key: 'first_node_task_id', optional: true
end
```

However, I found that I could no longer delete those **Nodes**, because of the reference to **NodeTask**. There was some weird reverse relationship going on with the foreign key constraint: `ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "nodes" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_696709283b" on table "node_tasks"`

How can I model my references so that **Node** can have a `first_node_task` set, which is a reference to an arbitrary **NodeTask**, without affecting the related **NodeTask**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out what I'm trying to do doesn't make sense.

Irrelevant to my `first_node_task` attribute, `Nodes` have a set of `NodeTasks`, so something needs to happen to those `NodeTasks` on `Node` deletion. Whatever happens to child `NodeTasks` will happen to the `first_node_task`, because it is one of them.

I realised that I *do* actually want `NodeTasks` to be deleted, which mean that if `first_node_task` is set, it would be deleted also.

I solved this by adding a migration to change the foreign key between `NodeTask` and `Node` to cascade on deletion, as so:

```
remove_foreign_key :node_tasks, :nodes
add_foreign_key :node_tasks, :nodes, on_delete: :cascade
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `dependent: :nullify` to

```
class Node
    belongs_to :first_node_task, class_name: 'NodeTask', foreign_key: 'first_node_task_id', optional: true, dependent: :nullify
end
```

Comment: No luck, unfortunately - but I think maybe this isn't what I'm trying to do. If a Node has a NodeTask set, and the Node is deleted, the NodeTask shouldn't be deleted as well, it should just exist regardless. The "first_node_task" attribute on Node should not create a relationship where the NodeTask is dependent on the Node, it should just be an optional reference to a NodeTask. Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: There is a way do delete a Node and not to delete a NodeTask. Use `dependent: :nullify' . It will make a foreign key null in NodeTask record. Answer edited.